# Example of accessing Watson IoT Last Event Cache from Node-RED

Tags: node-red, watson-iot

I am using the REST api for the Watson IoT Last Event Cache from an HTTP Request node.  The actual event data is returned encoded in Base64.  I run this through the Node-RED Base64 node and it is not properly decoded.
Does anyone have a working flow for this?

Comment: Can you edit the question to provide a sample so we can see what the data actually looks like

Answer (score -1):

The Last Event Cache call returns the event data in a 'payload' field under the normal msg.payload. Node.js can handle the string conversion using something like:

var s = new Buffer(msg.payload.payload, 'base64').toString('ascii');

Comment: You just copied this from https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/355028/does-anyone-have-a-working-example-of-accessing-th.html. Bad Form.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.   Also asking the same thing in multiple forums p*sses us of.

Comment: You're right...I did copy it....after I posted it there.  I apologize for the double posting and it won't happen again.